# NSString - rangeOfString issue finding a double quote

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, xcode9

This appears to be a bug with either iOS 11 or Xcode 9 since this worked in previous versions.  I'm attempting to parse a string containing a length in feet and inches, for example:  37' 6".  When I attempt to find the symbol for inches (double quote) using the command:

```
NSRange inchesrange = [lineOfData rangeOfString:@"\""];
```

the range is returned with a null pointer for the location and a length of 0 instead of the character location with a length of 1. Has anyone else noticed this?  I'm not sure what the work around would be (other than having users enter a decimal for the length in feet).

Thanks!
Rob

Comment: This seems to work for me when I try it; I'm getting a valid range with the location and length of the `"` character (for example, with the string `@"37' 6\""` I'm getting `{ 5, 1 }`). Can you post the specific string that is giving you the issue?

Comment: Also, this may seem like a dumb question, but have you checked to make sure the character in your string is indeed `"` and not something like `ʺ` or `”`?

Comment: I'm parsing a string that the user enters using the iPad keypad while the application is running; but you make a good point...  I believe I'm entering a double quote, but I haven't checked the character for what else it might be.  In the past it has been the same as what I'm parsing for.

Comment: It's possible that a “smart quotes” feature may be automatically converting quotes typed in the text entry widget into curly quotes.

Comment: One quick Google search later: [yup, iOS 11 apparently introduces a “smart” quotes feature](https://www.jordanmerrick.com/posts/ios-11-smart-punctuation/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cursory Google search reveals that [iOS 11 includes a “Smart Quotes” feature that automatically turns your straight quotes into curly quotes](https://www.jordanmerrick.com/posts/ios-11-smart-punctuation/). So your string probably contains `“` or `”` rather than `"`, which is why your search isn’t finding it.

Solution: make an `NSCharacterSet` containing `"`, `“`, `”`, and `ʺ` (since the latter is, y’know, the actual correct symbol for inches), and then use `-[NSString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]` to search for it, rather than `-[NSString rangeOfString:]`. This way, you'll find the character no matter which form it’s in.

Alternatively, it appears that the “smart quotes” can be turned off for an individual `UITextField` or `UITextView` by setting its `smartQuotesType` property to `UITextSmartQuotesTypeNo`.

(By the way, did you notice that all my apostrophes and quotation marks in this answer were the pretty curly kind? How about that attention to detail, eh?)

Comment: Thanks Charles!  I have to admit I never would have thought of that.  And yes, excellent attention to detail.  Thank you very much!